# Trying to solve for a variable within a choose function.

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve for lowest possible k in the equation:

$$1-\frac{{40 \choose 10-k}{10 \choose k}}{50 \choose 10} > .5$$

This comes from a question that I've only been able to brute force testing k = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. with k=4 being the answer.

That is all that's required of me, but it got me thinking about how to solve such questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can attack such problems: First rewrite the inequality as
$$
    \frac{\binom{40}{10-k}\binom{10}{k}}{\binom{50}{10}} > 0.5
$$
By using the definition of the binomial coefficient and some algebra, rewrite this as
$$
2\frac{40! 10! 10!}{41\cdot 42\dots 50} > (10-k)! (30+k)! k! (10-k)! =F(k)
$$
On the last line we have defined a new function $F(k)$, which is defined for $k=0,1,2,\dots, 10$.  We find again with a little algebra that
$$
F(k+1)=F(k)\cdot \frac{(31+k)(k+1)}{(10-k)^2}
$$
so $F(k)$ is increasing whenever$\frac{(31+k)(k+1)}{(10-k)^2}>1$.  That inequality can be solved to give $k > 1.87$, and since $k$ must be an integer that means from 2 on. So $F$ is decreasing for $k=0,1$ and increasing from 2 on. So there must be a minimum for $k$ equalt to 1 or 2.